# Max speed in simple harmonic motion

Tags: calculus

A particle moves in a straight line with simple harmonic motion about the centre $O$. The period of motion is $\pi$. When the particle is $0.5$ metres from $O$, it's speed is $2.4 $ $ms^{-1}$. What is the maximum speed?

I'm new to this topic so I don't really know what I'm doing. I tried letting $a=-n(x+k)$ where $n$ and $k$ are constants because that's the general form for all simple harmonic questions and then integrating for $v$ where I get $\frac12v^2=-\frac{nx^2}{2}-nkx+C$ but I don't know how to use the knowledge that the period $=\pi$ to find $n$ or $k$. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Distance is measured from the center, so that should be enough to decide on $k.$ The period is determined by $n$, and you can work that calculation backwards.

Comment: @DavidK So you're saying $n=\pi$ and $k=0$?

Comment: $k = 0,$ but recall how to calculate the period if you know the function for acceleration.

Comment: Is the period $\frac{2{\pi}}{n}$?@DavidK